# How to create a channel using discord.py and Python 3.6.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Right now I am using:

```
server = ctx.message.server
await client.create_channel(server, 'cool-channel', type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

to try and create a channel. However, every time I run this nothing happens. I have made sure my bot has all the correct permissions and I think I have all the correct modules imported. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 3.6.1 is your python version.  What version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: discord.py version 0.16.12

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore.
You should look into updating and [migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).